# Interface from multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have several objects that can be used in similar contexts, they inherit from different base classes.
I define a type interface to identify the class an object belongs to:

```
class type {
public:
    virtual int gettype() = 0;
};

class base1 {
public:
    //...
};

class base2 {
public:
    //...
};


class o1: public base1, public type {
public:
    int gettype() { return 1;}
    //...
};

class o2: public type, public base2 {
public:
    int gettype() { return 2;}
    //...
};
```

I have a pointer to an object

```
void* obj;
```

it could be of class `o1` or `o2`.

I know that it implements the class *type* but if I cast it directly to *type*.
it does not work. To use a `dynamic_cast` I should know class (`o1` or `o2`) it belongs.

How can I identify the type of obj
?

Comment: So, your question is how to get back the type information that you threw away? The answer is: don't throw it away. `void*` is a C idiom, and rarely appropriate in C++.

Comment: How an object of class `o1` and `o2` is translated into `void* obj`? It would help to do the reverse operation. If it is in different code parts, you should consider to translate them into `type*` instead of `void* obj`. No standard way to retrieve an access to the virtual method table from `obj` especially if base1 has no virtual method.

Comment: No need to find out the type. Add to `type` all the functionality you need, but have `base1` and `base2` inherit `type` and implement the functionality or leave it to a class further down the inheritance chain to implement. There should be little difference between how they are used even if the implementations differ greatly. If they are used differently, odds are really good they aren't related enough for inheritance to be a logical solution. The user just calls functions in `type`, not knowing they are actually calling child functions. Still need to discard the `void*` nonsense, though.